# Domino server: Passing JVM options to http task only

Tags: java, lotus-domino, jvm-arguments

For troubleshooting reasons I need to gain insight into what the garbage collector of the JVM the https tasks uses does. For this I can pass the required arguments (-verbose:gc and -Xverbosegclog:%some_path%) via an options file that is setup by the notes.ini setting JAVAOPTIONSFILE=%file%.

This works fine. However those options are also picked up by the JVM(s) started seperatedly by the amgr task. So different JVMs log into the same file which makes the analysis rather useless.

Is there a way to pass the required arguments to **only** the JVM used by the http task?

Comment: Can you just stop the agent manager (by running the `tell amgr quit` command on the server), then start it again when you've gathered enough logs? I'm fairly sure the agent manager only handles scheduled agents, and it may be OK if none of those run for an hour or so, depending on the environment.

Comment: Yeah, that's what we are doing right now. But I'd hoped we could proceed in a more elegant way.